# Age of the Earth without radiometric dating?

Tags: earth-history, dating

It is common knowledge that age of the Earth is roughly 4.5 billion years. Radiometric dating of meteorites (which were formed during the formation of Earth) and earliest rocks on Earth have both arrived at the same values. I was wondering if there are any other scientific methods which also support or concur with the radiometric techniques.